# Fastboot boot twrp.img just boots back into bootloader

Tags: fastboot, boot, bootloader, motorola

Im trying to boot in to the twrp.img for my Motorola Edge 20 (Berlin) because I can't flash it because my phone doesn't have an own partition for the recovery. fastboot says finished but my phone is just back in the bootloader where it was before

I tried:

- empty VBMETA with verity and verification disabled
- both fastboots (fastbootd and the fastboot in the bootloader)
- another version of twrp both versions dosent work

My console output:

```
fastboot boot motorolaE20TWRP.img
Sending 'boot.img' (26460 KB)                      OKAY [  0.643s]
Booting                                            OKAY [ 10.190s]
Finished. Total time: 10.846s
```

Comment: Immediately on flashing what happens if you `fastboot reboot recovery`?

Comment: My phone doesn't have an own partition for the recovery I can't flash it because of that I need to boot in it

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but is the bootloader unlocked via the code from Motorola?

Comment: Yes my bootloader is unlocked and my phone is rooted but I want to boot into twrp

Comment: Do you have the stock ROM image? Can you boot that recovery.img file?

Comment: Yes i have the stock ROM but I cant boot the twrp.img recovery